# Returning a pointer to the object that an iter points to using `&*iter`

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have an iterator and I want to return a pointer to the element it is pointing to.

Is this ok to do?

`return &*iter;`

It doesn't really seem like a good idea.

Comment: if vector<int> , then you would be returning *iter rather &*iter.

Comment: @jagansai: Why's that? [edit: just noticed mismatch in q]

Comment: @weezybizzle: Pointer to element or element? Pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine. But be aware that if the iterator is of a container which deallocates and reallocates memory on resizing, then the *returned* pointer will become invalid. For example, if the iterator is an iterator of `std::vector`, then `iter` and `&*iter` both become invalid if the underlying vector resizes itself.

By the way, the title of the topic and what you said in the very first line, do not match:

> Returning a pointer from an iter using `&*iter`  **(title)**
>
> I have an iterator and I want to return the element it is pointing to. **(first line)**

Both of these mean different. What you have written, i.e `return &*iter` is what you said in the title. But second statement means this:

```
return *iter;
```

It returns the element the iterator is *syntactically* pointing to. It does not return the *pointer* to the element. This is safe even if the vector resizes itself.

Comment: I overlooked that, sorry its really late here.